# Pyinstaller: It works, but .exe window and App Window is separated. Any ideas?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

The Tkinter app works good after deployment with Pyinstaller,
but it opens 2 windows: .exe and app (tkinter container).

Any ideas? how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand completely but you may want to try saving the file as .pyw vs .py before making it an executable. you may be seeing the console running.

Comment: Thank you, I saved it in .pyw and then ran pyinstaller, now I don't see console running, and app is like a app!.

Comment: Hi Uralbi, I'm glad I could help could! could you mark my post as answered because I think the question was closed by the system for being non specific